# How to install Pure-FTPd and configure FTP server to transfer files?

Tags: software-installation, pure-ftpd

I want to install Pure-FTPd and configure FTP server for transfer files. How can I do this? I am using Ubuntu 13.04.

Comment: Apparently PureFTPd is peculiar in it's configuration method, any reason you need it in particular? In any case, the Ubuntu help site has a guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PureFTP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Install Pure-FTPd**

```
root@www:~# aptitude -y install pure-ftpd
```

#### run as a daemon

```
root@www:~# echo "yes" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/Daemonize
```

#### prohibit Anonymous

```
root@www:~# echo "yes" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/NoAnonymous
```

#### enable chroot

```
root@www:~# echo "yes" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/ChrootEveryone
```

#### only IPV4

```
root@www:~# echo "yes" > /etc/pure-ftpd/conf/IPV4Only
root@www:~# /etc/init.d/pure-ftpd restart
Restarting ftp server: Running: /usr/sbin/pure-ftpd -l pam -E -A -8 UTF-8 -B -O clf:/var/log/pure-ftpd/transfer.log -u 1000 -4 -B
```

Answer (score 0):

I developed a guide to installation of PureFTP, MySQL and TLS on Xenial since I had some difficulties, maybe it will help.

http://ajoliveira.com/ajoliveira/uk/software/pure-ftpd-mysql.php

or in Portuguese

http://ajoliveira.com/ajoliveira/pt/software/pure-ftpd-mysql.php

The reason I installed PureFTP is explained in the guide I published, too many problems with proftpd, which became unusable after Trusty (passive mode, TLS) and had problems before (crashes). I found this package easy to install and working with no apparent flaws.

> I used ProFTPd for a long time. However on the previus Ubuntu LTS
>   (Trusty) ProFTPd was already buggy, shutting down by itself, which I
>   corrected with a script.
>
> On Xenial the situation become worse, with the product stopping but
>   not shutting down. On the other end I could never setup ProFTPd for
>   passive ftp transfers and TLS never worked properly since MLSD command
>   failed with TLS authentication.
>
> So, I decided to give PureFTP a try. I had to search for information
>   on many different sites since the main site has no information on the
>   obscure files used in the configuration directory. Those are
>   transcriptions of the command-line options with a distinct syntax.
>
> I found out that the installation is straightforward and repeatable
>   when you know the steps to take and the product works like a charm, so
>   I decided to share the installation process with the community.
>
> I assume you will use phpMyAdmin in what MySQK operations are
>   concerned and are familiar with it, so I will be providing an sql file
>   for the single needed database, and assume InnoDB or other
>   transactional engine. If you are using MyISAM, just comment the last
>   sentence on the provided mysql.conf(MySQLTransactions On). All bash
>   commands must be preceded with `sudo` or you may start a root session
>   with `su`.
>
> 1. Install the software.
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt-get install pure-ftpd-mysql
>    ```
> 2. Setup user and group.
>
>    ```
>    sudo groupadd -g 2001 ftpgroup  
>    sudo useradd -u 2001 -s /bin/false -d /bin/null -c "pureftpd user" -g ftpgroup ftpuser
>    ```
> 3. Setup the database.
>
>    Now using phpmyadmin on the server tab create an user called pureftpd, note the password you choose and click on "Create database
>      with same name and grant all privileges.".
>
>    Load this file and unpack it.
>
>    On the left-pane go to the pureftpd database just created and click on "Import". Select the file you just unpacked. You should end
>      up with a populated database with a single table where:
>
>    • User is the user name
>      • status is `0 inactive 1 active`
>      • Password is the password, encrypted in MD5 (choose MD5 after you enter the password on the varchar(64) dropdown. Change the password on
>      the test user provided or it will never work
>      • uid and gid will be 2001 (created on steps above)
>      • dir should point to the dir where you have the files. Either that dir is set to be owned by the user/group created (`chown ftpuser.ftpgroup "dir"`) or you might just add ftpuser to your
>      www-data group if we are talking about apache-served files.
>      • ULBandwidth and DLBandidth are the limits in kb/s for the upload/download maximum bandwidths, 0 means no limit.
>      • comment should serve your internal purposes for user identification.
>      • QuotaSize is the maximum space an user is allowed to upload.
>      • QuotaFiles is the maximum number of files an user is allowed to upload.
>
>    ```
>    sudo cp /etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf /etc/pure-ftpd/db/mysql.conf.old
>    ```
> 4. Configure PureFTP.
>
>    Load this file and unpack it.
>      Copy the mysql.conf inside the db directory to /etc/pure-ftpd/db/
>
>    Please change the string my_password on the mysql.conf file, MYSQLPassword field, to the password you defined when you created the
>      user with mysqladmin
>
>    Load this file and unpack it.
>      Copy all files inside the conf directory to `/etc/pure-ftpd/conf/`
>
>    It is assumed in these files that passive ports are 50000-50010 (PassivePortRange), no passive mode forcing (no ForcePassiveIP file,
>      if you want that create one and leave your IP there in a single line),
>      no automatic creation of user home directory (CreateHomeDir), no name
>      resolution (DontResolve), no display of hidden files
>      (DisplayDotFiles), no local user authentication (PAMAuthentication). I
>      increased the maximum number of files per folder and the maximum
>      directory depth (LimitRecursion) to 5000/50. If you want to change
>      those refer to the documentation.
>
>    ```
>    sudo aptitude install openssl
>    ```
> 5. Install ssl certificate.
>
>    ```
>    sudo openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem -out /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem chmod /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem
>    ```
>
>    -days 3650 will create you a certificate for 10 years...
>
>    ```
>    sudo chmod /etc/ssl/private/pure-ftpd.pem
>    ```
> 6. Putting it to work
>
>    ```
>    sudo service pure-ftpd-mysql restart
>    ```
>
> Well, it should work...
>
> Installation of the above is entirely at your risk.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/794481)

Comment: I see you did it already and I agree, nevertheless link will stay there, page is up for 14 years now. The advantage of link answers is that when you want to make a correction, there is just one place to go.

Comment: The imported text contains different wording than the original, I spotted at least a different word (MySQK instead of MySQL), I do recommend potential readers to read the original.